# Is there any way how to wait till purchase dialog will appear?

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-purchase

When user clicks on the purchase button, I want to change `_isLoading` variable to `true`.  Once purchase dialog will appear (on Android or iOS), then set `_isLoading` back to `false`.

For simplification, the flow I want:

1. User clicks on the purchase button (`_isLoading` is `true`)
2. Purchase dialog appears
3. `_isLoading` is `false`

I tried to do like this:

```
setState(() => _isLoading = true);
await _iap.buyConsumable(
  purchaseParam: PurchaseParam(productDetails: product),
);
setState(() => _isLoading = false);
```

But on iOS, the `_isLoading` immediately goes to `false` when user clicks.

Answer (score 0):

you have to listen the purchase lifecycle. IAP using streamer not async await

Answer (score 0):

**You can try with catch() and try() (exception handling)**

```
try {
  await _iap.buyConsumable(
    purchaseParam: PurchaseParam(productDetails: product),
  );
} catch (error) {
 //here you can print the occured error
}
setState(() => _isLoading = false);
```

Comment: I'm not encountering any exceptions, you maybe didn't understand my question

Comment: try with value listenable builder instead of setstate()..